# .net Maui Shell flyout menu items How to programmatically scroll to top (or other position)

Tags: .net, shell, maui

Is it possible to make a list of Shell flyout items/menuitems scroll to the top (or bottom or a position) by means of code (in a ViewModel - so how would I get a reference to the shell flyoutmenu?)

I've edited my actual code to show essential features.

AppShell.xaml

```
 <ShellContent                             <--- scroll so that this is visible
    Title="Display"
    Icon="speedometer.svg"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:DisplayPage}" />
  
  <ShellContent 
    Title="Bluetooth"
    Icon="bluetooth.svg"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:BluetoothPage}" />

  <ShellContent 
    Title="Tracks"
    Icon="tracks.svg"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:TracksPage}" />

... many items


  <MenuItem                    <--- so when this is clicked say scroll to top
    Text="Parameters"
    IconImageSource="parameters.svg"
    Command="{Binding ShowParametersCommand}" />  <--via this viewmodel

  <ShellContent 
    Title="Settings"
    Icon="settings.svg"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:SettingsPage}" />
```

ControlMenuViewModel.cs

```
namespace TSDZ2Monitor;

public partial class ControlMenuViewModel : ObservableObject
{
  //[ObservableProperty]
  //bool showMainMenu = true;
  ...

  public ICommand ShowParametersCommand => new Command(ShowParametersControl);
  public void ShowParametersControl()
  {
     //AppShell.Current.CurrentItem???   <--- do something here?
  }
}
```

Note my includes are in a GlobalUsing.cs and I use the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm (via nuget)

Comment: The feature is not supported in current Shell project, consider raising the feature request on github : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues.

Comment: Thanks, however, since everything is supposed to be about code re-use surely there is an underlying scroll base class that scrollable views *should* use and these do have the ability to scroll programmatically? Why can't I inherit in some way?  Probably a stupid comment, but I have to ask. :)

Comment: Yes , it should be  scrollable views  there , but the api does not expose the view , maybe you can seek the solution with the custom renderer , see the docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CollectionView for the FlyoutContent or FlyoutContentTemplate then execute the command on the CollectionView to scroll to the top.

Comment: I'll look into this when I get some time, it looks interesting, thanks.